# how to convert android web view in PDF in android programming and save as pdf file

Tags: java, android

***how to convert android  web view in PDF in android programming and save as pdf file***

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through these two pages - 
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Work perfect for me :) Use this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49891294/4557915

Answer (score 0):

if you ask about convert web page to pdf from android you need make back end .
Ex. you have web page view inside android web view. in this status you need make other file in your server to convert html 2 pdf (you can use HTML2PDF library ) to make that. after that you make button in your project in android to query the html file . in this way you will download the html and convert to pdf in you mobile . i wish help you